# FileOutputStream is not creating filename with UTF-8 encoding (JAVA)

Tags: java, linux, pdf, encoding, utf-8

I am generating a pdf which should be named something like this, "ウェブドメイン.pdf", but when I pass this filename into the FileOutputStream, it doesn't created the expected filename with UTF-8 encoding but instead it creates a file with a name like ???????.pdf.

I am using the following code to do the same, and I don't understand why is it behaving like this.

```
 String fileName="ウェブドメイン.pdf";
 FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(new String(fileName.getBytes("UTF-8"),"UTF-8"));
 PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document,fileOutputStream);
```

Anyone having ideas on how to solve this problem. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You console font probably won't be able to display japanese chars?

Comment: Please take a closer look at your code, and you'll understand that this is not an iText question. You create a `String` called `filename` and you use that `String` to create a `FileOutputStream`. Even if you wouldn't pass that `fileOutputStream` to a `PdfWriter`, the filename would be wrong.

Comment: Sidenote: "When mapping Unicode to a Japanese-language code page, WideCharToMultiByte and other conversion functions map both backslash (U+005C) and the normal Unicode Yen symbol (U+00A5) to this same character. For security reasons, your applications should not typically allow the character U+00A5 in a Unicode string that might be converted for use as a FAT file name." - [Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317748(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: `new String(fileName.getBytes("UTF-8"),"UTF-8")` is *exactly the same* as writing `filename`.  Converting a String to bytes and back again with the same charset does not affect the contents of the String at all.  All Strings have the same encoding (UTF-16) at all times and there is no way to change it and no need to change it.

Comment: Where exactly do you see `???????.pdf`? Please post a screenshot to clarify. I am almost certain that you will post a screenshot of your console, as @Fildor already suggested.

Comment: Actually @AmedeeVanGasse you are right.in linux console ??????.pdf it is shown.but the same thing if i transfer that file to windows it shows %3F%3F%3F%3F%3F%3F%3F.pdf..one more thing if i create directly from windows machine it creates perfect UTF-8 file with the name ウェブドメイン.pdf.and i have tried for comparison as file.exists() it gives true.so can you guide what can be the issue?

Comment: Check the language settings of your console. Unfortunately your question is outside the scope of iText so I won't be able to help you out any further.

Comment: Did yo find a root cause for this issue?
I have stumbled upon exactly this and my debugging took me all the way to `UnixFileSystem.java` in the Amazon Corretto code.

Answer (score 0):

In a Unix system, native code libraries seemingly pull the encoding information from `LC_CTYPE` environment variables to determine file encoding, instead of getting the value from `-Dfile.encoding=utf-8` java system setting.

If you `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8` your system environment, the native parts of java stack will treat your UTF filenames accordingly.